# Update total number of registered user count without page refresh

Tags: php, laravel, real-time

I am making some Real Time data application and I want display total number of user registered to my site.

The count should refresh automatically whenever a new user registers without refreshing page.

How can I achieve this?

I am using php, Laravel and MySQL

Answer (score 2):

EDITED:
What you need is called `Broadcasting`. You need to implement 2 things

- Subscriber: at your client's side, connect to your websocket server
- Publisher(your websocket server): at your server's side, waiting for any  subscriber's incoming connection

The basic idea is when you register an user, if succeed, at this time call the Publisher to send a message to it's subscribers to update the user count.(just like when you subscribe to someone youtube channel, when they upload a new video, you get a notification)

you can use https://socket.io/ to implement your client side
Laravel supported it also, find the Socket.io section [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting)

Comment: Thanks but I am new to laravel and not able to understand the documentation.Can you help me with some other good tutorial. I am registering user through different framework.Using same database in Laravel for display new users.

Comment: see my new edited answer above, let me know if this help @KritikaShrivastava

Answer (score 2):

You can use Laravel's Broadcasting, Laravel supports redis and pusher by default.,

**Configuring Broadcast**

There are set of configuration in `config/broadcasting.php`, just add the required configurations in the file directly or through `.env`

Before broadcasting any events, you will first need to register the  `app/Providers/BroadcastServiceProvider` . In fresh Laravel applications, you only need to `uncomment` this provider in the providers array of your `config/app.php` configuration file.

I personally using Pusher service, you will get a `PUSHER_APP_ID`, `PUSHER_APP_KEY` and `PUSHER_APP_SECRET`.

**Configuring Laravel -Echo (Js - to receive the broadcast)**

while using pusher, use laravel-echo js to listen  for events broadcast by Laravel, you can install through npm install

```
npm install --save laravel-echo pusher-js
```

In your app.js just add this to import and initialize the Echo and store in a window object

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'your-pusher-key'
});
```

**Sending Broadcast**

when defining broadcast events there are three different methods available `broadcastOn`, `broadcastWith`, `broadcastData`. Broadcast by triggering the event

```
event(new youBroadcastClassName($array))
```

**Receiving Broadcast**

```
Echo.channel('channel-name')
.listen('youBroadcastClassName', (e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

now it is available in the js you can use some js functions to show in the front end.

In your case once user is registered trigger the broadcast event with data  which you need in front end, just receive in the js and populate it in the view

Go through this link [Laravel Broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting)

Comment: Is it possible to use broadcasting even when I am not using Laravel to Register new user?

Comment: The thing is , when you broad cast something from backend , you are catching it with Echo and you can do what ever you want, but you have to send the required data to the front end.

Answer (score 1):

Use [brodacasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting) feature.

> In many modern web applications, WebSockets are used to implement realtime, live-updating user interfaces. When some data is updated on the server, a message is typically sent over a WebSocket connection to be handled by the client. This provides a more robust, efficient alternative to continually polling your application for changes.
>
> To assist you in building these types of applications, Laravel makes it easy to "broadcast" your events over a WebSocket connection. Broadcasting your Laravel events allows you to share the same event names between your server-side code and your client-side JavaScript application.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting will explore this.

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket absolutely the correct answer for this question. But for beginner I think you can always use `setInterval` and good old `ajax`.

I am not saying this is the most correct answer, but this would be much more simpler and easier.